# Typescript: map union type to a single type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, union-types

I am trying to narrow down (w/ inference) the type that I want out of this array filter, but it's giving me an TypeError: 'Item' is missing the following properties

```
type ItemList = (Item | ItemGroup )[];
type ItemGroup = {
  name: string;
  items: Item[];
}
type Item = {
  key: string;
  label: string;
}

const list: ItemList = [
   {
      key: 'key',
      label: 'label'
   },
   {
      name: 'name',
      items: [
        {
          key: 'key1',
          label: 'label2'
        },
        {
          key: 'key3',
          label: 'label4'
        },
      ]
   }
]

const groups: ItemGroup[] = list.filter( l => 'name' in l )
      ^^^^^^
// Type '(Item | ItemGroup)[]' is not assignable to type 'ItemGroup[]'.
//   Type 'Item | ItemGroup' is not assignable to type 'ItemGroup'.
//     Type 'Item' is missing the following properties from type 'ItemGroup': name, items ts(2322)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like `groups` should be typed as `ItemList`, because `filter` returns an array. The error message actually tells you what the problem is: there is no `name` for your `ItemGroup`.

Comment: sorry I miss typed that when I wrote the question, Its supposed to be `ItemGroup[]` (updating it now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the compiler isn't smart enough to look at the `l => "name" in l` callback and understand that it can be used to narrow an `Item | ItemGroup` to just an `ItemGroup`.  Luckily, you can *tell* the compiler that this is the intent by annotating it as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const isItemGroup = (l: Item | ItemGroup): l is ItemGroup => "name" in l;
```

Now if you call `isItemGroup(l)` and the result is `true`, the compiler will understand that `l` is an `ItemGroup`.  Additionally, the standard library provides a [call signature for `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c88e44a9e65f7d7a72ef72c9dfae94ef0fcb6bb0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1355) that accepts a user-defined type guard callback and produces a narrowed array.  So by using `isItemGroup` as the callback, you get your desired outcome:

```
const groups: ItemGroup[] = list.filter(isItemGroup); // no error now
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAyBLAzsKBeKAKOiUAPrPAgOIBOA9gK5gCUA2gLoDcAUKJKYlXWGxQA3hyhQAdgEMEEAFxQMlFBIDmncSjJoFBBK04BfLuGh6ho8QGsIIBUpXqxUADZSARhBf3gytUY4OAGNqCQxXdGBdMlRwnCZnS3EoGzsoAHJU9IAaKGdxN09vDMKvdOdDbMT8yRl5DOlZHJqtRB0oBOTkpK7rWwVM2wBGZt7k0uL0iYAmcrHKmvEe3tSB1IBmUbHXDy8BiYAWOd6FrpYKjnPg0PD0PX56IVxi8xJ7mnoGBRcodF4KD6CLAAPigACJGhAwb8JK5ONcwphVID2u8BKwhC5IgA6ABmKBc8EouDuZAejA4QA)

Comment: you beat me to posting by 38 seconds!

Comment: @LindaPaiste For a second I thought I had posted the same answer twice, as they are eerily similar. 

Comment: Ahh okay, this makes sense. In the mean-time I was using a lodash reduce function and just checking the next value contains the 'name' prop. I like this function though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have a array which contains both `Item` and `ItemGroup` elements.  You want to filter this array to just the elements which are `ItemGroup`, and you want typescript to understand that you have filtered the list and know that the returned type is `ItemGroup[]`.

How you can achieve this is buy turning the filter `l => 'name' in l` into its own type guard function.  The return type `value is ItemGroup` tells typescript "if and only if this is true, value is of type ItemGroup".

```
const isItemGroup = (value: Item | ItemGroup): value is ItemGroup => 'name' in value;

const groups: ItemGroup[] = list.filter( isItemGroup );
```

By using a type guard, typescript can understand the meaning of `list.filter` and your error goes away.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAyBLAzsKBeKAKOiUAPrPAgOIBOA9gK5hQCUA2gLoDcAsAFCiSmIqdBjgDePKFAB2AQwQQAXFAyUUUgOZduklGTRKCCNloC%20PPtEPYo47VADWEEEpVrNEqABsZAIwieXYFUNUx4eAGNqKQwvdGADMlQYnGYPGzTJByclAHJHEByAGgzJbz8AqByy-xy0k2K7dMbM2Xlc1ogikqhdRH0oVObMpuHRrOdK-IBGLqHR6oqq338AJlq5yXruyVsx4fzc-IBmWb3MhdyFgBZ1s6251jqeR%204IqJj0QyF6a1wANxknloigECGIoO%20YEYSgBQOg6AhNB%20WAAfJUOjkelIoLDgVo3tFMOokWB%20l8SWxrJ44gA6ABmKE88EouB6aHJwiY7CAA)

Comment: This also works
`const groups = list.filter((value): value is ItemGroup => 'name' in value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that your filtered resulting array is of type `ItemGroup[]` using [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

`const groups: ItemGroup[] = list.filter( l => 'name' in l ) as ItemGroup[]`